# Problem with run vagran dxf-viewer in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dxf

I need help with running the dxf-viewer (https://github.com/vagran/dxf-viewer/). The available version to run is written in vue.js, which I am not familiar with. I would like to run a simple version using only HTML and JavaScript to parse the dxf file located at the source path: /path/test.dxf. How can I achieve this?

Please help me! :-( I have tried to run the available version in vue.js, but I am having difficulty working with it.